# Can't get specific version of composer package

Tags: composer-php

I am trying to get latest version of calcinai/xero-php (just doing composer require as per their readme installs v ^1.7)

When I run

```
composer require "calcinai/xero-php":"^2.0.4"
```

The incorrect version of this package is downloaded (composer logs below + vendor code being installed is not what is in master repos, currently at v2.0.4).

[image]

How do I get v2.0.4/latest code that is on master (using composer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to require a **specific** version, and not any other, skip the caret. Installing **exactly** v2.0.4 of that package works using

```
composer require "calcinai/xero-php":"2.0.4"
```

Comment: [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package calcinai/xero-php in a version matching 2.0.4

-could be they haven't published to packagist?

Comment: I've just tried it, and it works. Which version of Composer are you using?

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/calcinai/xero-php also lists that version

Comment: Composer version 1.9.1 2019-11-01 17:20:17

Comment: ok found the issue. local composer was looking for a forked version of this package. thanks Nico for the help, obscure one ...